# Hard potential scattering cross-section as a function of degree of sphericity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I've just finished a course that included material on elastic, hard-potential scattering. To be clear, in the spherical case, this is a potential of the form:
$$
V(r) = \begin{cases} 0,& r>R_0\\\infty, &r\leq R_0 \end{cases}
$$

In the low-energy regime, $kR_0<<1$, we know that the potential is transparent for all but the s-wave ($l=0$) component. Where the phase shift for this component is then $\delta_0 = -kR_0$. It can then be shown that this results in
$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} \approx R^2\\
\rightarrow \sigma_{tot} = 4\pi R_0^2
$$

Which is exactly 4 times the geometric cross-section, or what the impinging waves "see" classically, which is an interesting result in and of itself, but my question is, what would the effect of "stretching" the sphere along the impinging axis. My thinking is that this would change the area visible to the incoming particle and so would affect the total cross-section in some way.

Consider a parameter $\gamma$, defined as the sphericity of the potential along the impinging axis. For convenience, we can define it as the following,
$$
\gamma = \frac{r_{n}}{r_z}
$$

where $r_n$ and $r_z$ are the radii of the potential normal to the z-axis and along the z-axis respectively. See the somewhat crude drawing below

[image: Schematic of sphericity definition for clarity]

My initial guess would be that since the heuristic "visible" area increases with $\gamma$, so would the total cross-section. At some point, the potential may also not be transparent to higher-l partial wave components.